# python global variable __name__ (a newbie question)

Tags: python

What are the following names when I first start my python shell? They do not look like functions from `__builtins__`:

```
>>> dir(__name__)

['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', 
'__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__',
 '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 
'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs',
 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace',
'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace',
 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split',
 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper',
'zfill']
```

Answer (score 8):

`__name__` is a string and those a string methods. It's the name of the module or `'__main__'` on the toplevel. Hence this idiom appears often:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this file was called directly, not imported
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

`dir(__name__)` shows the attributes of `__name__`, and since `__name__` is a string, it shows the attributes of the `str` class.  Most of the listed attributes are methods.  You can get more information using `help()`:

```
>>> help(str.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    S.index(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Like S.find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
```